# Do URL parameters In Google Webmaster Tools need just a name, or both a name and a value?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, url-parameters

We're working on a new e-commerce store (subdomain) and have noticed that Google has crawled much of the store subdomain pages already.

The issue is that they have a ton of URL String Parameters included in the indexed results, like this:

`https://store.oursite.com/en-us/widget/accessories?sort=Price`

I've gone into Google Webmaster Tools and added in parameters for them not to index:

- p
- pageSize
- sort
- sortorder
- categorybase
- redirecturl

Would that be enough to block something like that example URL above? In other words, I don't need to add `sort=Price` as a parameter too, do I?

Also, after doing this, will Google eventually remove those URLs from the SERPS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the feature correctly.  You only need to provide the parameter name and Google will use "one representative URL" for all values associated with that name.  If your page works without the parameter, the "one" URL will generally be without the parameter at all.

This will cause these URLs to stop being crawled and indexed eventually.

You could also look into to using [rel canonical link element](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en) to tell Googlebot that the page without parameters is the preferred "canonical" URL.